# rake:db rollback does not delete the migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have entrees and snapshots. An entree has_many snapshots. I forgot to add the foreign key to snapshots. So I later added migration:

```
$ rails generate migration add_snapshot_ref_to_entrees snapshot:references
```

Migration file looked like this:

```
class AddSnapshotRefToEntrees < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :entrees, :snapshot, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

This did not do what I want. It added an snapshot_id to entrees, rather than adding an entree_id to snapshots.

So I run the rollback:

```
bundle exec rake db:rollback
```

It correctly moves the following from schema.rb:

```
add_foreign_key "entrees", "snapshots"
```

And also correctly rolls back the database itself. But the migration file remains in db/migrate. Am I suppose to remove this myself or did not complete its job?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to remove this file **manually**. Regarding your association, it should be as below:

```
class AddSnapshotRefToEntrees < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :snapshots, :entree, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not supposed to.

`rails destroy migration add_snapshot_ref_to_entrees`

Answer (score 0):

In order to rollback a specific migration use:

> rake db:migrate:down VERSION=YOUR_MIGRATION_VERSION

For Example:

> rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20100905201547

To find the version of all migrations, you can use this command:

> rake db:migrate:status

Answer (score 0):

rake db:migrate:down and rollback worked on database label it's not   removing file from db/migrate.

You need to remove direct from db/migrate folder.